# A question related to the sum-of-divisors function

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

In what follows, let $\sigma$ be the sum-of-divisors function, and assume that we have $\sigma(a^b)\sigma(c^2)=2{a^b}{c^2}$ together with $\gcd(a,c)=1$ and integers $a, c > 1$.  Let $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$.  We assume further that $a$ is prime.

If $c < a^b \leq \sigma(c) \leq \sigma(a^b)$, then it follows that $b > 1$ and
$$1 \leq \frac{\sigma(c)}{a^b} \leq I(a^b) < I(c) \leq \frac{\sigma(a^b)}{c} < 2.$$

My question is this:

> Does it follow that $$a^{b - 1} < c?$$

Here is my attempt:

> Since $a^b \leq \sigma(c) < 2c$, then we have $a^{b - 1} < \frac{2}{a}\cdot{c} \leq c$, because $a$ is an integer together with $a > 1$ implies that $a \geq 2$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Could you show how you get $b>1$ and $\frac{\sigma(a^b)}c<2$?

Comment: @JaycobColeman, from my assumption that $a$ is prime with $a^b \leq \sigma(c) \leq \sigma(a^b)$, it follows that $b > 1$, because otherwise $b = 1$ and $a \leq \sigma(c) \leq \sigma(a) = a + 1$ would violate the fact that $a$ and $a + 1$ are consecutive positive integers.

Comment: @JaycobColeman, I get $\frac{\sigma(a^b)}{c} < 2$ from $a^b \leq \sigma(c)$ and the fact that ${a^b}{c}$ is a proper factor of the *perfect* number ${a^b}{c^2}$ (and is therefore *deficient*).

Comment: I don't see why we can't have $a\leq\sigma(c)\leq a+1$, but it doesn't look like $b>1$ gets used in the proof anyway. Otherwise the proof looks correct.